# Can't migrate Django models with foreign key constraints

Tags: django, django-migrations

I have a model with a foreign key field. I want to remove the foreign key reference. However, migration fails because of the following error:

```
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

I understand *what* is going on, but I don't know how to resolve this properly with Django. Right now (since I'm at the beginning of my project), I go into the MySQL database manually and delete the tables and re-migrate as if it was the first migration.

Is there a way, using Django, to get around this foreign key constraint issue?

---

I'm using Django 1.7
Database backend is MySQL

**EDIT - Models Before/After migrations**

*Before*:

```
class Skills(models.Model):
  # fields here...

class Project(models.Model):
  skills = models.ForeignKey(Skills, verbose_name = "Required Skills", blank = True, null = True)
```

*After*:

```
class Skill(models.Model):
  # fields here...

class Project(models.Model):
  skills = models.ForeignKey(Skill, verbose_name = "Required Skills", blank = True, null = True)
```

I'm pretty sure all I've done is removed the "Plural" from the `Skill` model. The the `makemigrations` command works fine, but the `migrate` command fails with the above noted error.

---

**EDIT 2**

Hit the same error:

```
Cannot drop column 'skills_id': needed in a foreign key constraint 'projects_project_skills_id_4cc7e00883ac4de2_fk_projects_skill_id'
```

This time I dropped the field `skill` from model `Project`

Comment: This is an error you can expect when you are deleting or updating a row; not when you are changing database schema. Can you post your models (before and after migration)?

Answer (score 1):

A little hack I used:

- Add a migration operations that first alters the field to say IntegerField before other operations i.e

`operations = [
    migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='projects_project',
            name='skills',
            field=models.IntegerField(default=0)
        ),
  ..... other migration entries now after this.
]`

Comment: Your hack worked for me. I had this same issue adding a ForeignKey column. I used `migrations.AddField(...UUIDField...)` first for the field then put the `AlterField` after.

Answer (score 0):

This is my SOLUTION (do this manually first)

> ALTER TABLE forms_formentry DROP FOREIGN KEY
> forms_formentry_form_id_d0f23912_fk_forms_form_page_ptr_id

This is the ERROR

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1833, "Cannot change column 'page_ptr_id': used in a foreign key constraint 'forms_formentry_form_id_d0f23912_fk_forms_form_page_ptr_id' of table 'dbname.forms_formentry'")
```